# permanent storage of parameter names in bytecode using javac -parameters <Classname>

Tags: java, reflection, command-line-interface, named-parameters

## What I'm doing

I'm using reflection in my code to decouple all my classes and To do so I need to be able to dynamically create instances of objects. I've done this by text matching parameter names to input data. To do a text match however, I need access to the formal parameter names rather than the synthetic `arg0, arg1 ...` that I know gets created if `IsNamePresent` returns false.

## What I've done

I researched how to get the formal names (google searching things like: "when I compile my java classes with the parameter option enabled, does that make reflection work forever? or only one time when the classes are run?" to no useful results). I've also tried searches similar to that here and seen info related to javac with one of the questions being "Drawbacks of javac -parameters flag" as an example. While these addressed parts of my question they really didn't answer the meat of what I need. I've found that in java 8 you can just do "javac -parameters " and you will be fine. Note that I had to use the directory of the jdk as the starting point (my command line input looks exactly like this):

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin>javac -parameters C:\Users\abbotts1\IdeaProjects\project\src\Sales_Rep_Data\*.java
```

and so far that works without any errors and my project has bytecode compiled files in it now so I know its doing something. Just what exactly (or if its as a result of the above) is a mystery to me because there is no timestamp or anything I can find for these files that points to which command I tried that made it (I've been trying these commands for a while).

## Detailed description of question scope

My question is this: is this command line input the only way to get formal parameters. If it is then, am I doing it right (correct input syntax)? If I'm doing it right then how can I make it so that when I debug my code and run param.getName() it actually returns the formal name? So far I've ran the above command on the command line and tried to debug in my java code this line:

```
Boolean check = param.isNamePresent();
```

where param is just the parameter coming from a for-each loop that uses the constructor of the class I am getting through reflection. Point is, every-time I run it this Boolean returns false in the debugger and the names are synthetic (arg0, arg1 ect). I want it to return true (and actually use the formal names) so I can debug the rest of my code.

If this isn't the only way to achieve the stated goal of getting formal parameter names then where can I find a better way? I've seen some framework stuff and heard of Eclipse being used to do this, however I don't want to get too deep into new software just to accomplish one thing AND I am working so I don't have administrator privileges (which is why I needed to specify the jdk in cmd directly rather than just set the PATH variables the usual way). This would make it a hassle to have to download something like Eclipse.

## Update

I've researched into using annotations to get the parameter names since I have no good idea why the compiled class won't actually store the parameter names. This strategy was suggested in an initial answer (since deleted) and I took it upon myself to go learn some basic annotations. They have worked to a point but right now I'm getting a wrong arguments error where I shouldn't. I've checked the debugger and the number of arguments passed in are the same number needed so it must be a type error with the wrapping/unwrapping according to the javadoc for the `newInstance(Object[])` method). I want to be able to initialize `null` parameters and I think thats the source of my problem (i. e. null type errors or something but not shown as NPE). Other potential sources include the fact that I'm passing in an `Object[]` and typing it stricter in the class (i.e. `newInstance(Object[] array)` is creating an instance of a class that has String parameters and other various sub classes of `Object` including array lists) Since asking about that error here would constitute an XY problem I won't ask but just describe it for clarification on the original question. My original question still stands even as this workaround is being worked on because I'd still love to know why compiling this class with the -parameters flag didn't store the parameter names. I'm 99% sure the class path is correct since I copy pasted it from the directory. This sounds silly but do I have to actually run the class using the below line?

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin>java C:\Users\abbotts1\IdeaProjects\project\src\Sales_Rep_Data\Data_Parser.java
```

I was under the impression that compiling it with the parameters flag was all you needed and then the formal parameter names would be available.

Comment: "I'm using reflection in my code to decouple all my classes". But....why? Did you read that decoupling is good, so you want to take it to the extreme?

Comment: Related: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodparameterreflection.html

Comment: I wanted to learn the guts of dependency injection and decoupling and I was told this was how to do it. TBH I've seen a lot of frameworks that do stuff like this for you but I think doing it this way as a side project kind of thing helps me learn how all this works. It really is teaching me a lot about DI, Factory Pattern, Properties, Reflection ect ect. Now if I could just get good with the command line...

Comment: Actually frameworks do it with annotations, since it's not guaranteed that the parameter names are present, and the names are actually irrelevant since it's the types that matter. There's a bit of a gap here when you say you want to learn the inner workings of advanced things, yet you don't have decent tooling or a strong grasp of the command line. Besides, don't you have your own computer where you can install whatever you want, if this is supposed to be a side project?

Comment: I do but I haven't gotten around to moving the files and plus, after working I don't feel like coding so I code while I have time at work because sometimes there isn't anything to do If I'm just waiting for bosses to get back to me on stuff. I'd rather do something productive and learn rather than surf the web and watch cat videos. Also I know I really need to learn about tooling and command line (a lot of this question is learning the command line).

Comment: So, the crux of the question is that you've compiled with `-params` as you should, but when you run the program afterwards with `java MyClass` it's giving false for `isNamePresent()`?

Comment: Well I'm not 100% sure that I compiled correctly but I'm 99% sure. Hence that being addressed in the question. But if indeed I did compile right then yes that would be the crux of the question.

Comment: Well make sure you're running the correct class. You don't seem to be getting a compiler error and there's nothing else suggesting you've compiled wrong. I'll have to go now, but I'll take a looksie tomorrow morning if this hasn't been solved.

Comment: Appreciate the help. Update: Currently researching: [link]https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html